# Lotus notes script: create and open unsaved clone doc

Tags: lotus-notes

in lotus notes 6.5.6 i have a document and inside this there is a  "clone doc" button that create a copy of the uidoc and open it in workspace.
My problem is that when the cloned document is opened in the workspace is already saved and i don't want this. i have already check in the "Queryopen", "Postopen"... states but there isn't a doc.save call. So, how can i open a new cloned doc in my workspace without saving it ?
Here is my wrong code.

```
    Dim session As New notessession
    Dim uiw As New notesuiworkspace
    Dim uidoc As notesuidocument
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim newdoc As NotesDocument
    Dim NewUIDoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim doc As notesdocument    
    Set uidoc=uiw.currentdocument
    Set db=session.currentdatabase
    Set doc=uidoc.document  
    Set newdoc = db.CreateDocument
    Call doc.CopyAllItems( newdoc)
    Set NewUIDoc = uiw.EditDocument( True ,newdoc)
```

Comment: I tested your code and the newly created document is not saved. The problem must be somewhere else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You -wrongly- assume, that the document is "saved", most probably because "@IsNewDoc" and NotesUiDocument.isNewDoc both return FALSE on any document that has been created in LotusScript prior to opening it with uiw.EditDocument.

This is a well known flaw in the design of Lotus Notes. You need your own function, to check if a document is new.

In Formula I usually use a computed for display field called "IsNewDoc" that contains the formula:

```
@Modified = @Created
```

For LotusScript I have an own function that looks like this:

```
Function MyIsNewDoc( doc As NotesDocument ) As Boolean
    MyIsNewDoc = (doc.Lastmodified = 0)
End Function
```

Comment: is there a place where i can find a description of others Lotus Notes programming flaws ?

Comment: It's not a flaw; @IsNewDoc and IsNewDoc are only true for a document that is being composed (created by opening a form). In this case, the document already exists before being called into the UI for editing. The back-end method NotesDocument.IsNewNote will be true if the document has never been saved.